# MS Access ODBC Error 6623: A Winsock virtual circuit was aborted

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I tried to create a query with multiple tables in it, all work fine except that when I add this one table, I got ODBC call failed error

> 6623: A Winsock virtual circuit was aborted.

I used Advantage SQL to link the external database to create reports from it.

The sql for the query that gives the error:

```
SELECT podetail.ItemPartNbr
      ,podetail.ItemDescription
      ,Sum(podetail.Qty) AS LastYearOrdQty
FROM poheader
    LEFT JOIN podetail
        ON poheader.PoNbr = podetail.PoNbr
WHERE poheader.PoDate >= DateSerial(Year(Date())-1,Month(Date()),1)
    and poheader.PoDate <= Date()
GROUP BY podetail.ItemPartNbr
        ,podetail.ItemDescription;
```

The main sql where I want to combine other tables with the query above:

```
SELECT 
    itemmast.ItemPartNbr
  , itemmast.Description
  , Sum(iteminv.QtyOnHand) AS SumOfQtyOnHand
  , itemmast.MinOrderQty
  , itemmast.Cost
  , Sum(iteminv.QtyAllocated) AS SumOfQtyAllocated
  , itemmast.ReOrderQty
  , QtyLastYearPurchase.LastYearOrdQty
FROM 
  (itemmast 
    LEFT JOIN iteminv ON itemmast.ItemPartNbr = iteminv.ItemPartNbr) 
    LEFT JOIN QtyLastYearPurchase ON (itemmast.Description = QtyLastYearPurchase.ItemDescription) 
      AND (itemmast.ItemPartNbr = QtyLastYearPurchase.ItemPartNbr)
GROUP BY 
    itemmast.ItemPartNbr
  , itemmast.Description
  , itemmast.MinOrderQty
  , itemmast.Cost
  , itemmast.ReOrderQty
  , QtyLastYearPurchase.LastYearOrdQty;
```

I set the joint fields by the `ItemPartNbr` and I just need the `QtyLastYearPurchase.LastYearOrdQty` from the first query above to be added into the second query.

I tried to open each one of the queries/tables including the one that gives error and they all open just fine individually, so it doesn't have anything to do with the connection.

If I remove `WHERE (((poheader.PoDate)>=DateSerial(Year(Date())-1,Month(Date()),1) And (poheader.PoDate)<=Date()))` from the first query, the second query can display the records just fine, but it takes extremely long to show the records.

Any recommendation to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to create queries between the `itemmast` and the `iteminv` tables, and connect the `itemmast` table with the query i just created and the first query I posted. It works now for now, except that it is still taking forever to open.

This is a bit troublesome since I have to create multiple queries just to combine them all into one query. I have almost 20 queries just to create three reports.